# How to create Azure Managed Disk Snapshot with Encryption and Network Access Policy?

Tags: azure-java-sdk

I am trying to use the SDK to create a snapshot for the managed disk using the below

```
azureSdkClients
        .getComputeManager()
        .snapshots()
        .define(snapshotName)
        .withRegion(disk.regionId)
        .withExistingResourceGroup(context.resourceGroupName);
        .withWindowsFromDisk(context.azureDisk)
        .withIncremental(incr)
        .create()
```

But this doesn't have the options for setting **encryption** and **network acess policy**? Is it supported by the SDK API ? or should I use a different API ?
I see **SnapshotInner** as one implementation of **Snapshot**. I am not sure if I can use the inner class as it doesn't allow me to set the name of the snapshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps

SDK

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager-compute</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager-keyvault</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code

```
        String clientId="";
        String clientSecret="";
        String tenant="";
        String subId="";
        AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(tenant,subId, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        TokenCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
                .tenantId(tenant)
                .build();



        ComputeManagementClientImpl computeClient = new ComputeManagementClientBuilder()
                .pipeline(HttpPipelineProvider.buildHttpPipeline(credential,profile))
                .endpoint(profile.getEnvironment().getResourceManagerEndpoint())
                .subscriptionId(profile.getSubscriptionId())
                .buildClient();

       SnapshotInner sp = new SnapshotInner()
                .withCreationData(new CreationData().withSourceResourceId("")                                             .withCreateOption(DiskCreateOption.COPY))
                .withSku(new SnapshotSku().withName(SnapshotStorageAccountTypes.PREMIUM_LRS))
                .withEncryption(new Encryption().withType(EncryptionType.ENCRYPTION_AT_REST_WITH_PLATFORM_KEY))
                .withNetworkAccessPolicy(NetworkAccessPolicy.ALLOW_ALL)
                .withLocation("eastasia");

        computeClient.getSnapshots().createOrUpdate("testdata","testdfg",sp);
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.resourcemanager.compute.fluent.models.snapshotinner?view=azure-java-stable).

Comment: Thanks a lot @jim

The only issue I found is `.withLocation("eastasia")` returns a Resource object and not a SnapshotInner object. So the location has be set separately.